# BETWEEN operator in filter expression

Tags: hana, between, hana-sql-script

I have to write a condition where I have to check a "DATE" lie beween two other date values as shown in the example:

```
var_out= CE_PROJECTION(:table1,["col1","col2","col3","col4"],  ' " col2"  BETWEEN "col3" AND "col4" ' );
```

But this throws me an error  `SQL: transaction rolled back by an internal error: Syntax Error in filter expression`

Could anyone suggest the right syntax for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between is not supported in the filter expression of  CE_PROJECTION.

You can try

```
var_out= CE_PROJECTION(:table1,["col1","col2","col3","col4"],  ' "col2" >= "col3" AND "col2" <= "col4" ' );
```

Hope it helps.